# Shooting Star (Probability)

Tags: probability, self-learning

Assume that a random experiment consists in centering a telescopic sight on a random star. Let $A_{n}$ ($n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$) denote the event that the telescopic sight spots exactly $n$ stars. Suppose that $P(A_{n})=\frac{6}{\pi^{2}n^{2}}$. Assume further that star shootings occurs independently for various stars and that the probability of a given star to experience this over a one hour period is $10^{-6}$.

> What is the probability that one will observe some star shooting within an hour of study?

I am lead to the disastrous conclusion that I should write $P(S)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_{n})*10^{-6}$, which clearly does not converge...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Bit worried about your astronomy but never mind. lets call $q=10^{-6}$

Given that you see n stars probability that you don't see one shooting is $(1-q)^n$
Thus probability that don't see a star shoot in a random experiment is $\sum_n A_n (1-q)^n = \frac{6}{\pi^2} L_2(1-q)$.  Where $L_2$ is the special function the polylogarithm.

So probability you do see a shooting star is 1 minus this quantity, which for small q is $\approx \frac{6}{\pi^2} \left(q +\frac{q^2}{4} \right)$.